# Hibernate Table is not being created automatically

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I have been trying to get my Java application with Hibernate to connect to MySQL database in localhost:3306 and create a table, but it's not happening.  it gives error.  But the same code works when i create a table beforehand by the given name and then run the app, it inserts all data in the table accordingly.

in hibernate.cfg.xml file i have tried to set my
"update" to both update and create.  None of it works when there is no table called "Alien" in the database.

As per my understanding when this option is set to "Update", it creates a table and inserts the data (when the table doesn't exist and it just inserts the data when the table already exists.

Please help me solve this issue.

Here are my codes:

```
pom.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ksk</groupId>
<artifactId>Hibernate Project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependencies>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
       <version>6.0.6</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->

       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
       <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
   </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>

    <!-- Assume test is the database name -->

    <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myHibernate
    </property>

    <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">
        ksk235
    </property>

    <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">
        password
    </property>
    <property name = "hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Alien.java

```
package com.ksk;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Alien {
@Id
private int aid;
private String aName;
private String color;

public Alien(){};



public int getAid() {
    return aid;
}

public String getaName() {
    return aName;
}

public String getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void setAid(int aid) {
    this.aid = aid;
}

public void setaName(String aName) {
    this.aName = aName;
}

public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
}
}
```

App.java

```
package com.ksk;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Alien kaushik =new Alien();
    kaushik.setAid(101);
    kaushik.setaName("Kaushik");
    kaushik.setColor("Green");


    Configuration config = new 
Configuration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(Alien.class);
    SessionFactory sf = config.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session =sf.openSession();

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(kaushik);
    tx.commit();
}

}
```

The error I'm getting can be viewed in this link:
https://1drv.ms/w/s!AgnhrqMHRiyJjfll32wEkDQRSOQ4Yw

[Here's my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJV9V.png)

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** In file `hibernate.cfg.xml`,

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

should be

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

**(2)** You also need point out file DDL use for automation task, for example

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">classpath:/WEB-INF/classes/myfolder/myfile.sql</property>
```

Quote

> File order matters, the statements of a give file are executed before
>   the statements of the following files. These statements are only
>   executed if the schema is created ie if hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set
>   to create or create-drop.

e.g. /humans.sql,/dogs.sql

See reference document: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-misc-properties